# Thymeleaf - how to add a custom util?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Thymeleaf has a number of useful utilities like `#strings.capitalize(...)` or `#lists.isEmpty(...)`. I'm trying to add a custom one but have no idea how to register this.

Have made a custom Util class:

```
public class LabelUtil {

    public String[] splitDoubleWord(String str) {
        return str.split("[A-Z]", 1);
    }
}
```

Now I'm going to use it like this:

```
<span th:each="item : ${#labels.splitDoubleWord(name)}" th:text="${item}"></span>
```

Of course, it won't work because I haven't registered the Util and defined `#labels` var.

So, the question is how and where to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### This answer is for thymeleaf 2.x.

### If you use thymeleaf 3.x or later, please see other answers.

```
public class MyDialect extends AbstractDialect implements IExpressionEnhancingDialect {

  public MyDialect() {
    super();
  }

  @Override
  public String getPrefix() {
    // @see org.thymeleaf.dialect.IDialect#getPrefix
    return "xxx";
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isLenient() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalExpressionObjects(IProcessingContext ctx) {
    Map<String, Object> expressions = new HashMap<>();
    expressions.put("labels", new LabelUtil());
    return expressions;
  }
}
```

and register your dialect.

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

  @Bean
  public MyDialect myDialect() {
    return new MyDialect();
  }
}
```

[thymeleaf-extras-java8time](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-java8time) source code is good reference for creating custom thymeleaf expressions.

Answer (score 11):

The API for registering a custom expression object has [changed in Thymeleaf 3](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/extendingthymeleaf.html#expression-object-dialects-iexpressionobjectdialect), for example:

```
public class MyDialect extends AbstractDialect implements IExpressionObjectDialect {

    MyDialect() {
        super("My Dialect");
    }

    @Override
    public IExpressionObjectFactory getExpressionObjectFactory() {
        return new IExpressionObjectFactory() {

            @Override
            public Set<String> getAllExpressionObjectNames() {
                return Collections.singleton("myutil");
            }

            @Override
            public Object buildObject(IExpressionContext context,
                    String expressionObjectName) {
                return new MyUtil();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCacheable(String expressionObjectName) {
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to register multiple util classes using only 1 dialect?

Comment: @BrianAntiqueña yes - just return a set with multiple strings in `getAllExpressionObjectNames` and return the appropriate util class in `buildObject` based on `expressionObjectName` - that will be `"myutil"` in ryanp's example.